# Converting magnitude ratio to complex form

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to inquire as to how we can convert a magnitude ratio, given in dB, to complex form, in real and imaginary form, provided of course that we have the phase given as well.

Eg. Suppose I have an S-parameter reading as -11dB with a phase of 1.4 radians

How would I go about a situation like this? I wish to use this formula to create [touchstone](http://na.support.keysight.com/plts/help/WebHelp/FilePrint/SnP_File_Format.htm) (.s1p) files from a list of input reflection coefficient (S11) values.

Comment: Did the answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S parameters are supposed to be a ratio of two voltage phasors, e.g.
$$S_{21} = \frac{V_2}{V_1}$$
where $V_2$ and $V_1$ are complex numbers.
However, when S parameters are reported in dB, you are actually getting the dB form of the *square* of the S parameter.
To be specific, if someone tells you that $S_{21}$ has a value of "X dB", then what they mean is this:
$$10 \cdot \log_{10} \left( \left \lvert \frac{V_2}{V_1} 
\right \rvert^2\right) = X$$
This is a ridiculous abuse of language that is unfortunately very common in engineering.
Rearranging the equation, we find
$$\left \lvert \frac{V_2}{V_1}\right \rvert = 10^{X/20} \, .$$
From there you can add in the phase, if you know it, to get the complex voltage ratio.

Comment: Straight and to the point. Thanks a bunch! And I am guessing to get the real and imaginary values I would just have to use [X * cos(phase) = real] and [X * sin(phase) = imaginary]?

Comment: @Vith yes, that's correct